# JRE 9 module requires a module that was not found

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

When running my project I get the error that says:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.soap not found, required by java.xml.ws
```

As far as I understand `java.xml.ws` is a JRE module and `java.xml.soap` is not, based on the list provided in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/overview-summary.html). The way I start my program is:

```
java --upgrade-module-path c:/git/projectdir --add-modules java.xml.bind,java.xml.ws,java.xml.ws.annotation  -cp c:/git/projectdir/Uservice.jar com.gert.DynamicService "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"
```

When I try to add `java.xml.soap` to add-modules it cannot find the module.

My question is:

- is the `java.xml.soap` a JRE module?
- if `java.xml.soap` isn't a JRE module, why does the `java.xml.ws` module depend on a module that isn't in the JRE?
- where to find the `java.xml.soap` module?

I'm using java 9.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the java.xml.soap a JRE module?

No, this is a not a platform module. Run `java --list-modules` and you will not see `java.xml.soap` in the output.

> If java.xml.soap isn't a JRE module, why does the java.xml.ws module depend on a module that isn't in the JRE?

There are two `java.xml.ws` modules.

The first one is a platform module and it is deprecated (you should not use it).

The second one is a standalone module which is deployed to Maven central as `jaxws-api` (you should use this module).

While these two modules are similar, there are a number of differences. One of them is that standalone `java.xml.ws` has its own dependencies. E.g. `java.xml.ws` depends on `java.xml.soap` which is deployed to Maven central too (as `javax.xml.soap-api`).

> Where to find the java.xml.soap module?

See above. You can find it in Maven central. If you use Maven, it should be picked up automatically as a dependency of `jaxws-api`.

I think, `java.xml.soap` is missing in your upgradeable folder `c:/git/projectdir`. You should copy the jar from `.m2\repository\javax\xml\soap\javax.xml.soap-api`.

Comment: In that directory I have an older (Java 8) jar that was build with dependencies. One of those dependencies is the maven `javaws-api`. It doesn't work when it is a dependency?

Comment: I mean, my jar doesn't export the `javaws-api` dependency? And then it uses the jre one?

Comment: @GertKommer The arg in case you are expecting the directory to provide automatic module(from the previous jar if I am not mistaken) should be just `--module-path`. You upgrade only available upgradeable modules, not the one's which are not present in the JDK.

Comment: @nullpointer Obviously, he doesn't want to use `--module-path`. He wants to run the app in an old style (via classpath). That's why he is using `--upgrade-module-path`.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Well I am quite sure the usage of `--upgrade-module-path` is incorrect here in either case(classpath or modulepath). Would expect OP to clear on the thoughts of implementation though. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624 for the args difference between `--module-path` and `--upgrade-module-path`. I don't see a correlation of classpath as well with either of these.

Comment: @nullpointer I think his usage is totally fine. I replicated the same on my computer and it's working fine. I put all upgrade modules to a local folder and run `java --upgrade-module-path folder -cp ...` and I confirm that java is using upgrade modules instead of platform modules.

Comment: @GertKommer Can you share the contents of `c:/git/projectdir`? Does it contain all necessary jars (including `javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar`)?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov like I said in my question that it just contains my own project jar with the dependencies included. Not the `javax.xml.soap-api` jar. However, I told maven to save my dependencies in `c:/git/projectdir/lib` and when I point to that directory I get an error related to my xalan dependency which i have to fix first...
@nullpointer `module-path` instead of `upgrade-module-path` works thx :)

Comment: @GertKommer If you replaced`upgrade-module-path` with `module-path`, then you just switched to the old platform deprecated modules. I think the proper way to fix your issue is too specify both `module-path` and `upgrade-module-path`: `java --upgrade-module-path c:/git/projectdir/lib --module-path c:/git/projectdir ...`

Comment: Hmm. Please help me understand something. the link nullpointer gave in his comment says the following about the `--upgrade-module-path` argument: *Each directory is a directory of modules that replace upgradeable modules in the runtime image.* This line implies that the module has to exist in the module-path that is loaded with the bootloader and that the `upgrade-module-path` contains a newer version of that module. So if my jar in `module-path` contains the newest version of my modules than I don't need `upgrade-module-path` and if it doesn't have the newest version it is needed? Correct?

Comment: @GertKommer `then I don't need upgrade-module-path` - no, you need `upgrade-module-path` because otherwise JVM will use the platform module, not the external one. The only possibility to **override** upgradeable platform modules is to put their external versions to the `upgrade-module-path`.

Comment: @GertKommer I think this link can help you with understanding upgradeable modules: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320

Comment: @GertKommer By the way, I was wrong that `--upgrade-module-path` is the only way to override platform modules. You can also put all modules to the classpath. So, `java -cp c:/git/projectdir/lib/jaxws-api-2.3.0.jar;c:/git/projectdir/lib/javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar;c:/git/projectdir/Uservice.jar ...` should work too.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I found a definition in JEP 261: *The upgrade module path (--upgrade-module-path) contains compiled definitions of modules intended to be used in preference to the compiled definitions of any upgradeable modules present amongst the system modules or on the application module path (compile time and run time).* JEP 261 also contains a list of the system modules that are upgradable. Thank you for helping me out with the whole java 9 module topic. It is a bit puzzling(pun intended) but quite an enjoyable experience to learn it:)